# Quadrupole and Multipoles in Physics

Tags: cosmology, multipole-expansion

I am a little confused over the notion of quadrupole and higher moments in physics in general.

The first time I saw it was in electromagnetism, when we did multipole expansion to analyze higher moment contribution to potentials.

But now I see things like "Stokes parameter Q is nonzero if and only if the incident radiation has quadrupole moment", or that "the stress energy tensor has only monopole contribution", etc.

My question isn't about these, but rather how exactly one should view the notion of quadrupole and perhaps higher monopoles, apart from thinking of it as just Taylor expansion of a problem. Could anyone explain what does it mean for $X$ to have quadrupole moment, whatever $X$ may mean? Or is this ill-defined question?

Comment: It's not Taylor expansion.  It's expansion in the basis for function space given by spherical harmonics.

Comment: @user1504 thanks. Do you know what is a good way to think of it physically of each moment?